# "inotifywait" to watch several directories simultaneously

Tags: linux, inotify

I want to trigger an action, when in one of my specified directories, a new file is created. I want to use `inotifywait` for this purpose. But the problem is that I don't know how to use `inotifywait` to watch several directories simultaneously. Watching a single directory even recursively is not a problem, but several? Is it possible, or must I run several processes with "`inotifywait`" in parallel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just list directories you want to observe:

```
$ inotifywait testdir1 testdir2/ -m
```

Inside application, after instance of inotify is created using [inotify_init()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_init) function, [inotify_add_watch()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_add_watch) can be called several times for selected paths. You can find the system limit of watching paths in `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` (8192 by default).

Comment: THX You for help